# Python how to strip a string from a string based on items in a list

Tags: python, string, list, strip

I have a list as shown below:

```
exclude = ["please", "hi", "team"]
```

I have a string as follows:

```
text = "Hi team, please help me out."
```

I want my string to look as:

```
text = ", help me out."
```

effectively stripping out any word that might appear in the list `exclude`

I tried the below:

```
if any(e in text.lower()) for e in exclude:
         print text.lower().strip(e)
```

But the above `if` statement returns a boolean value and hence I get the below error:

```
NameError: name 'e' is not defined
```

How do I get this done?

Comment: why did the comma disappear?

Comment: That was me typing in a hurry. The punctuation can be there or not be there. Doesn't matter for my output. I will fix the question though to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
>>> from string import punctuation
>>> ' '.join(x for x in (word.strip(punctuation) for word in text.split())
                                                   if x.lower() not in exclude)
'help me out
```

If you want to keep the trailing/leading punctuation with the words that are not present in `exclude`:

```
>>> ' '.join(word for word in text.split()
                             if word.strip(punctuation).lower() not in exclude)
'help me out.'
```

First one is equivalent to:

```
>>> out = []
>>> for word in text.split():
        word = word.strip(punctuation)
        if word.lower() not in exclude:
            out.append(word)
>>> ' '.join(out)
'help me out'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Use this (remember it is case sensitive)

```
for word in exclude:
    text = text.replace(word, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are not worried about punctuation:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "Hi team, please help me out."
>>> text = re.findall("\w+",text)
>>> text
['Hi', 'team', 'please', 'help', 'me', 'out']
>>> " ".join(x for x in text if x.lower() not in exclude)
'help me out'
```

In the above code, `re.findall` will find all words and put them in a list.
`\w` matches `A-Za-z0-9`
`+` means one or more occurrence

Comment: I am not sure why someone downvoted, but one reason could be that this would break words like `can't` into two separate words `can t`.

Comment: yep but in note i have given if OP dont care about punchuatation

Answer (score 0):

This is going to replace with spaces everything that is not alphanumeric or belong to the stopwords list, and then split the result into the words you want to keep. Finally, the list is joined into a string where words are spaced. Note: case sensitive.

```
' '.join ( re.sub('\W|'+'|'.join(stopwords),' ',sentence).split() )
```

Example usage:

```
>>> import re
>>> stopwords=['please','hi','team']
>>> sentence='hi team, please help me out.'
>>> ' '.join ( re.sub('\W|'+'|'.join(stopwords),' ',sentence).split() )
'help me out'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using simple methods:

```
import re
exclude = ["please", "hi", "team"]
text = "Hi team, please help me out."
l=[]

te = re.findall("[\w]*",text)
for a in te:
    b=''.join(a)
    if (b.upper() not in (name.upper() for name in exclude)and a):
        l.append(b)
print " ".join(l)
```

Hope it helps